# ¿como puedo crear un buscador para 2 datatables?

Tags: jquery, datatables

encontré este código

```
var table1 = $('#table1').DataTable();
var table2= $('#table2').DataTable();
var table3= $('#table3').DataTable();
var table4= $('#table4').DataTable();
var table5= $('#table5').DataTable();

$("[aria-controls='DataTables_Table_0']").on( 'keyup', function () {
    table1.search( this.value ).draw();
    table2.search( this.value ).draw();
    table3.search( this.value ).draw();
    table4.search( this.value ).draw();
    table5.search( this.value ).draw();
} );
```

lo que hace es que en el buscador de la tabla `DataTables_Table_0` si escribo algo busca en las table1.....table5, si escribo algo en mi tabla principal busca en todas las demas tablas, lo e adaptado a las tablas que necesito pero no hace nada, ese codigo donde lo encontre si funciona pero a la hora de ponerlo en donde lo ocupo y adaptarlo no me funciona o tal vez no sea eso lo que necesito.

Comment: Hola Juan Jose, tu pregunta es interesante y se ajusta bien a la temática del sitio, pero le faltan detalles importantes para poder comprenderla. Por favor edita tu pregunta para añadir un [mcve] en el que podamos ver el código completo (datatables y html y JS relacionado) y de ese modo podamos ver el problema específico y ayudarte mejor. Lee [ask] y completa el [tour] para más información.

Comment: revisa mi respuesta a una pregunta, acerca de un buscador, seguro lo puedes adaptar a tu problema y podrás hacer lo que necesitas: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/221674/como-establecer-buscador-individual-en-columna-de-tabla-con-datatable/221700#221700

Comment: @NoéAlonsoRabadán bien creo que me va aservir el keyup para realizar la busqueda

Answer (score 0):

Yo resolví algo similar de la siguiente manera

```
<input class="form-control m-0" type="text" placeholder="Búsqueda" name="buscador_inicial" id="buscador_inicial"/>

var table = $(tableId).DataTable({
            paging: false,
            ordering: false,
            info:false,
            autoWidth:false,
            fixedHeader: {
                header: false,
                footer: false
            }
        });

var prioritarias_table = $(prioritarias_tableId).DataTable({
            paging: false,
            ordering: false,
            info:false,
            autoWidth:false,
            fixedHeader: {
                header: false,
                footer: false
            }
        });

$('#buscador_inicial').on('keyup', function(){
            let busqueda = $(this).val();

        table.search(busqueda).draw();
        prioritarias_table.search(busqueda).draw();
    });
```

Me funciona de maravilla y me muestra los resultados de acuerdo a mi búsqueda, espero te sirva, saludos.

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe brevemente qué hace el código. Recuerda que [es.so] no es un repositorio de código, además, puede que tú comprendas cómo funciona, pero otros usuarios que podrían beneficiarse de tu respuesta puede que no. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.